# Unexpected ggplot output when trying to weight histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am trying to create a histogram and weight the output by a variable.  In this example, I would like a histogram of `value` weighted by `amount`. I did search prior posts but this did not seem to address my issues.

I have 2 problems I am trying to solve:

1. I expected different weighted results in the histogram.  I expected the "2" value to have a bar equal to 16%, the "3" value to have a bar equal to 24%, the "4" value to have a bar of 18%, and the "5" value to have a bar of 42%.
2. I don't know why a black bar at "0" value equal to 100% shows up in the histogram.

Here is the reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)

amount <- c(rep(0.02, 50), rep(0.03, 50))
value  <- c(rep(2, 20), rep(3, 30), rep(4, 15), rep(5, 35))
my_df  <- data.frame(amount, value)

xvar   <- my_df$value
weight <- my_df$amount

histogram <- ggplot(my_df, aes(xvar)) 
histogram <- histogram + geom_histogram(aes(weight))
histogram <- histogram + geom_histogram(binwidth=0.25, 
                         colour="black", fill="white")
plot(histogram)
```

Comment: There's a lot wrong with your `ggplot` code itself, regardless of your intended output, but in order to help I need to back up and ask about the weighting. 20% of the values are 2's. Can you explain how you expect to get a weighted value of 0.16 from that, given your data, because that part makes no sense to me.

Comment: ...more specifically, if you say you want a weighted histogram, I would have suggested `ggplot(my_df,aes(x = value,weight = amount)) + geom_histogram()` which produces a histogram of `value`, weighted by `amount`. But that doesn't appear to produce what you describe, so I'm trying to figure out what you actually want.

Comment: Thanks very much joran.  Hopefully I am thinking about this the right way.  The sum of **amount**  = 2.5.  For a single item with a **value** = 2, the percent is 0.02/2.5 = 0.8%.  So all of the 2s would represent 0.8%*20 = 16% since there are 20 items with a value of 2.  I know the code here is not compact, but I wrote it that way so someone could see what each successive line of code would do to the histogram.  When I used your code the black bar problem I had indeed went away (I tried this before but got an error...must have typed it wrong). The weighting is not what I expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what I was doing wrong.  Thanks again joran, you still definitely helped me out.  I think I was thrown off by the units on the y-axis and I needed to add **pct** as below to get the results I expected.

I didn't realize that weight here sums up **amount** for every "2" value instead of the percentage of the total **amount** that is a "2" (i.e., 0.02*20 = 0.4 instead of the 0.02*20/2.5 = 16%).  The graph bars look relatively the same, the units are just different.

I also wrote the code more compactly but would love any tips to make it better.

Here is my revised code which got me what I wanted:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

amount <- c(rep(0.02, 50), rep(0.03, 50))
value  <- c(rep(2, 20), rep(3, 30), rep(4, 15), rep(5, 35))

my_df  <- data.frame(amount, value)
my_df <- my_df %>%
  mutate(pct = amount/sum(amount)) 

histogram <- ggplot(my_df,aes(x = value, weight = pct)) +
geom_histogram(binwidth=0.25, colour="black", fill="white")

plot(histogram)
```

Finally, I noticed the placement of weight as below also works and I found this a bit confusing because I don't know if there is a single correct place to add weight:

```
histogram <- ggplot(my_df,aes(x = value)) + 
geom_histogram(aes(weight = pct), binwidth=0.25, colour="black", fill="white")
```

Comment: Regarding your confusion: The aes(-thetics) for a single command are automatically inherited from the previous command. This allows specific layers to take "the same aesthetic as before but with the additional parameter x". In you case, try adding another geom_histogram() between the two lines and see what happens :)